# Pre-push git is not triggering

Tags: bash, git, push, hook

I read all the pre-push stackoverflow questions and I followed every single instruction but still my hook is not triggering when I call git push

here is my hook

```
#!/bin/bash

protected_branch='master'
echo "Pre push hook is running..." # Even this line I can't see it in the output
current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')

if [ $protected_branch = $current_branch ]
then
        echo "You can't push to master directly"
        exit 1 # push will not execute
else
        exit 0 # push will execute
fi
```

I also made sure the hook file is named pre-push, and I made sure it has execute permissions.

I really can't see what am I missing, all I want to do is to just trigger the hook. and I'll figure out the rest.

Note: I have this repo and hooks on Debian 8 Jessie

Comment: Where did you put the file?

Comment: @Biffen I put it under .git/hooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two glitches in your hook. First, in one push, there could be more than one ref to be updated and you might have more than one protect branch. Better to test all of them. Second, you can push a branch that's not the current one. So it's not safe to test the current branch.

Here is a hook based on the template [pre-push.sample](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/templates/hooks--pre-push.sample). You can find a local copy of `pre-push.sample` under `.git/hooks`.

```
#!/bin/sh

protected_branch='refs/heads/master'
echo "Pre push hook is running..." # Even this line I can't see it in the output

while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
    if [ "$remote_ref" = $protected_branch ];then
        echo "You can't push to master directly"
        exit 1 # push will not execute
    fi
done

exit 0
```

Name it `pre-push`, grant it executable permissions, and put it under `.git/hooks` of the local repository.

Here is a sample of `pre-receive`. It should be deployed under `.git/hooks` of the remote repository.

```
#!/bin/sh

protected_branch='refs/heads/master'
while read old_value new_value ref_name;do
    if [ "$ref_name" = $protected_branch ];then
        echo "You can't push to master directly"
        exit 1
    fi
done

exit 0
```

Reference: [pre-push](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push), [pre-receive](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/githooks#pre-receive)

Comment: Thanks for your response it is very useful pointing out both glitches in my hook. I used your pre-push hook, I put it in ``.git/hooks`` and I gave it executable permission, but still it is not triggering the push to master is being done and the post-receive hook is running. Can by any chance having a pre-push and post-receive hook together making a problem? I am really out of ideas why the hook is not triggered.

Comment: I would be happy to give you more info or even screenshots if you need any, just let me know if you need any more info. Thanks again

Comment: @AliElKhateeb SInce you mentioned `post-receive` and it's in the remote repository, I wonder if you put `pre-push` in the local repository. If it was in the remote repository, a push in the local repository won't trigger it. Besides, please check your local config `git config -l` to see if you have specified `core.hookspath`. If it is, you should put `pre-push` under this path instead of `.git/hooks`.

Comment: so the pre-push hook should be local not in the remote, now I get it that makes so much sense now. So I guess pre-commit, pre-push and similar hooks should be all in the local.

Comment: @AliElKhateeb If you want to prevent a push from updating `master` in the remote repository, what you need is `pre-receive`. It's put in the remote repository.